# Ionic Reactjs Parsing error: Expression expected when rendering element based on Select Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I have a select element with 2 options which is `Examination` and `Consultation`. If the user choose `Consultation` I want to render an element which is a time picker. But if the user choose `Examination` It will not render the specific element. I tried doing an conditional statement inside return but something went wrong.

```
const Tab2: React.FC = () => {
  const [schedType, setschedType] = useState('');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState('');

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Book Schedule</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
      <IonItem>
        <IonLabel>Select Appointment</IonLabel>
        <IonSelect onIonChange={e => setschedType(e.detail.value!)}>
          <IonSelectOption value="Consultation">Consultation</IonSelectOption>
          <IonSelectOption value="Examination">Examination</IonSelectOption>
        </IonSelect>
      </IonItem>
        <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Select Date</IonLabel>
          <IonDatetime displayFormat="MMM D" min="2015" max="2030" value={selectedDate} 
          onIonChange={e => setSelectedDate(e.detail.value!)}></IonDatetime>
      </IonItem>

      if(schedType == "Consultation"){
       return(
        <IonItem>
          <IonLabel>Time</IonLabel>
          <IonDatetime
            hourValues='1,2,3,4,5,7,8'
            displayFormat="hh:mm A"
            minuteValues="0,30"
            value={selectedDate} onIonChange={e => setSelectedDate(e.detail.value!)}
          ></IonDatetime>
        </IonItem>
          )
        }

      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Ionic with react seems different in declaring props and state. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this and what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inline this conditional in jsx:

```
{schedType === "Consultation" && (
  <IonItem>
    ...
  </IonItem>
)}
```

Docs: [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: i got the same error `Parsing error: Expression expected`. Is `jsx` and `tsx` have a different structure? because in ionic its `tsx`

Comment: Can you give give a full example of what you tried? To be clear there should only be one `return`

Comment: its okay now sir. is `tsx` file different from `jsx`? i tried react js and for me it has something different than ionic which is `tsx`

Comment: To answer "is `tsx` different from `jsx`". **Yes** `tsx` extensions stands for a typescript file that has jsx syntax inside of it while `jsx` is for plain javascript with jsx.